# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with continuous uniformly derivative . Show:

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with continuous uniformly derivative . Show:
$\lim_{n \to \infty } n[f(x+1/n)-f(x)]=f'(x)$

I have tried the following: Since $f'(x)= \lim_{h \to0 }[f(x+h)-f(x)/h]$ so if $h=1/n$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty } n[f(x+1/n)-f(x)]=f'(x)$, I am well?

Comment: is continuous  uniformly

Comment: @AbdallahHammam 
how I could use MVT?

Comment: Is it ok with MVT?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I do not quite understand....

Comment: Any function differentiable on $\mathbb R$ satisfies that. The uniform continuity of $f'$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following trivial equality
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to0}h$$
$$\implies$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\implies$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}=f'(x)$$
by definition of the derivative and by equality $\eqref{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

By MVT

$$f(x+\frac1n)-f(x)=\frac1n f'(c_{x,n})$$

and

$$n(f(x+\frac1n)-f(x))=f'(c_{x,n})$$

with $$x<c_{x,n}<x+\frac1n.$$

when $n\to +\infty$,

$c_{x,n} \to x$ and as $f'$ is continuous,

$$f'(c_{x,n}) \to f'(x).$$